# Excel-like table for counting costs with html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a table with three rows. With three columns and n amount of rows.

The three columns have headers name, quantity and total.

The name needs to be an object which holds the price as parameter.

I have all the objects created and the table aswell, but I can't get the total row to work so that it takes in a user input for the quantity and multiplies it with the price of the product.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table width="700" height="500" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width=50% height=100>
            <p id="p1"></p>
        </td>
        <td width=25% height=100>
            <input type="number" name="qua" value="" />
        </td>
        <td width=25% height=100>
            <MATH>p1*qua</MATH>
        </td>

    </tr>
<!--with an n amount of <tr></tr> tags. 
//To get a scope there will probably end up around 300.-->

<p id="p2"></p>
<p id="p3"></p>

<script>

function product(price, pcode, des){
        this.price = price;
        this.pcode = pcode;
        this.des = des;
}
        var p1 = new product(10, "p1", "des1");
        var p2 = new product(20, "p2", "des2");
        var p3 = new product(25, "p3", "des3");

document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = p1.price;
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = p2.price;
document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = p3.price;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can probably tell the code is very clumsy... I am a total beginner as I started this project (and my first HTML and JS) two weeks ago, so please keep it simple.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code as slightly as possible to implement the desired functionality in the existing structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table width="700" height="500" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width=50% height=100>
            <p id="p1"></p>
        </td>
        <td width=25% height=100>
            <!-- add a function call here -->
            <input type="number" name="qua" value="" onchange = "setTotal(this, p1)"/>
        </td>
        <td width=25% height=100>
            <!-- add a span with id here -->
            <span id = "p1_total"></span>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table><!-- you forgot to close table-->

<!-- with an n amount of <tr></tr> tags. 
To get a scope there will probably end up around 300. -->

<p id="p2"></p>
<p id="p3"></p>

<script>

function product(price, pcode, des){
  this.price = price;
  this.pcode = pcode;
  this.des = des;
};

function setTotal(inp, prod) {
  //get integer value from
  var qua = parseInt(inp.value, 10);

  //calculate total
  var total = prod.price * qua;
  //total might be NaN if an incorrect value is given by the user
  //you can check this with isNaN(total) and display an error

  //set total as text content of product span (or error)
  document.getElementById(prod.pcode+'_total').textContent = isNaN(total) ? "###" : total;
}

var p1 = new product(10, "p1", "des1");
var p2 = new product(20, "p2", "des2");
var p3 = new product(25, "p3", "des3");

//use textContent here to set the numbers    
document.getElementById("p1").textContent = p1.price;
document.getElementById("p2").textContent = p2.price;
document.getElementById("p3").textContent = p3.price;


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle for you with an example on how you can do it in pure javascript:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mowday/3T9Ct/

Basically I have created a new function for you:

```
// Adds a product to the table
function addRow(product)
{
    // Get the table reference
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");


    // Get the number of rows
    var noRows = table.rows.length;
    // Create a new row at the end of the table
    var row = table.insertRow(noRows);

    // Create the three cells
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

    // Populate the first row with the price
    cell1.innerHTML = product.price;

    // Create an input field and add it to cell2
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.value = 1;
    cell2.appendChild(input);

    // Listen when the user enters anything into the input field
    input.onchange = function() 
    {
        // And when the user does input something update the last cell value
        cell3.innerHTML = Number(input.value) * product.price;
    };

    // Call the onchange function ones to populate the last cell
    input.onchange();
};
```

You have to seperate HTML from Javascript. HTML by itself is static (not entirely true) so you can't update values dynamically or perform maths calculations based on values inside HTML.
That's where javascript comes in. So I cleaned up the table to only contain the column names, and then the new javascript function creates a new row for each product and ties it's values together creating a dynamic table.
So to add more products, you simply call the function again and pass in the product.

**That being said**, it's a lot easier to use jQuery and something like jqGrid.
jQuery allows you to setup datamodels that can be visualised easily by jqGrid. It's always good to learn the basics and learn how javascript works, but do check out jQuery as well!